# Interpreting Odds Ratios for Natural Log transformed Variables

Tags: logistic, odds, clogit

For those who are using Stata the following command `clogit Y X,or` would produce the odds ratio from the Conditional logistic regression which is the change in the odds of Y for a unit increase in X. How can I interpret the odds ratio for a natural logarithmic transformation of X?